# Bearded dragon has weird mark on mouth/beard area?

Tags: health, skin-condition, bearded-dragon

[image: bearded dragon]

This is Z he is in the middle of shedding but I realized a small little like black scale a couple days ago and now where that black scale was is this larger area of discoloration. Is it because of shedding or maybe because of how young (not even two months old). is it common to have an area like that for dragons or is this something to be concerned about.

Answer (score 4):

I went to a pet store and the reptile specialist said it was nothing to worry about if your bearded dragon has something like this it may have accidentally put its face in its poop or in my case gotten hornworm blood when it was eating live. If this is the case for you get a qtip (cotton swab) with warm water and try wiping it off. It may take a bit but it may eventually come off. If this doesn’t work for you I’m sorry it maybe something else. possible reason to go to the vet.